# Iterating Orlicz norms

Tags: real-analysis

Associated with a convex function $\phi:[0,\infty)\mapsto[0,\infty)$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} = 0, \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x} = \infty,$ the Orlicz norm of a random variable $X$ is defined as:

$$||X||_\phi:=\inf\left\{c>0: \mathbb{E}\left[\phi\left(\frac{X}{c}\right)\right]\leq 1\right\}~.$$

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables and $f:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be any measurable function. Define

$$g(y):= ||f(X,y)||_\phi,\ \forall\ y\in\mathcal{Y}~.$$

> I conjecture that
>   $$||g(Y)||_\phi\leq ||f(X,Y)||_\phi~.$$

This is indeed true when $\phi(x) = x^p$ for $p\geq 1,$ in which case the Orlicz norm is simply the $L_p$ norm. Is it true for general $\phi$?

Comment: Actually, the conjecture is false, a counterexample was provided to me by Ramon van Handel (http://www.princeton.edu/~rvan/) as follows: Let $X,Y\sim\mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ taking values in $\{0,1\}.$ Let $\phi(t) = e^t-1,$ and let $f(x,y) = xy.$ In this case, $||g(Y)||_\phi = \frac{1}{(\log 3)^2}>||f(X,Y)||_\phi = \frac{1}{\log 5}.$